# How do I make and use my own C library in VSCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Win7 (32bit) VSCode (1.70.2)

I am learning VSCode (not Visual Studio) by rewriting some of my programs in C, and I'd like to make my own library with my own functions.

Is there a good tutorial on this subject?

Or can someone at least outline the steps so I can do further searching on the internet?

Thanks, Mark.

Comment: I have never use VS Code but [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) seems to indicate that it is an editor, and the actual development tools are separate. For Windows, you can choose between MSVC and MinGW. How you create and use libraries is different between the tool sets, and I'd recommend to use cmake to be independent of any specific platform anyway.

Comment: Bottom line: Focus on your (command line)  tools first, create a minimal working example, and only when that works use VS Code to edit more complex code.

Comment: If on windows you are likely wanting to create a `.dll` (dynamic link library) if on Linux, then either `.a` (static library - large zip file containing executable for the functions) or a `.so` (shared object library - object file containing the object code for your functions) to be linked with your program. Which OS are you using? Or just search either "*How to create windows dll in C*" or "*How to create a shared object library in C*" Or "*... static library ...*". There are concise tutorials for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 parts to this:

1. Writing your own C-library.
2. Integrating your custom C-library in VSCode with things like build toolchain, Intellisense, debugging etc.

VSCode is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE), a tool that enables you to write code in any language. The actual source code doesn't care what IDE you use (it could just be a text editor) but IDE's have many added features that make code writing more enjoyable and efficient.

For 1. You could look into some resources like https://diveintosystems.org/book/C2-C_depth/advanced_writing_libraries.html which will go over how to set up and link your custom library.

For 2. you mostly just need to tell VSCode the include path for your library and it should more or less *just work*. See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense for example. The reference provided for part 1. also has a section on [compiling/linking](https://diveintosystems.org/book/C2-C_depth/advanced_libraries.html).

Comment: Thank you tdpu. I found your first link very helpful. I have been programing in C for years, just recently dived into C++ (I am doing a bunch of IoT with Arduino) and all my libraries have been a collection of C functions I just included in my main C file. This is a step up. As for the intellisense, I personally never found much use for that. I don't like code completion, although the little reminders about the function arguments are helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help, I'm currently facing the same prospect - I've got a bunch of C files that are lacking overall organization and ability to re-use functions etc. It's a bit (a lot) more work at the start, but for a larger project, it will pay off in the end.